# how to show API view combining a Dictionary and a Model serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a dictionary containing two countries and a model outlets which have choice field for country. Now i want to make an api which shows array of outlets but the outlets should be categorised inside array of those countries in choice field.
[image: Result Like This]